# Windows Forms (.NET Core) is missing in the Visual Studio Community 2019

Tags: winforms, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

I have a problem which I struggle for 3 days. It seems that my Visual Studio Community 2019 doesn't want to recognise the ".Net core" for Windows Forms. I even install it manually (downloaded from Microsoft - .NET Core 3.1 SDK) but doesn't help. I used this blog [Microsoft blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-core-windows-forms-designer-preview-1/). They said that I have to install " Windows Forms .NET Core Designer VSIX package" because "it isn’t yet bundled with Visual Studio", but there is no link to download. I don't have ".NET Core" in "Project solutions" and "Visual Studio Installer" (I cannot download it from the installer). The version of VSC 2019 - 16.8.2
SS:

[Installer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wr1s.png)

[Project Picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30UMX.png)

[Installer2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeKfk.png)

[Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWm7M.png)

Comment: Try to report a problem on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/post.html?space=8).

Comment: When I installed it, I had to enable the designer in VS -> Options

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I had the same problem and yes you can't find .NET core windows form directly to open windows form that support windows form you will need to first open non .NET framework  windows from app there you can select if you want core which version.
[Windows Form Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GY9Yt.png)

[Selecting Desired Framework](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2wKQ.png)

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to select **Windows Forms App (.Net)** from the available project types and that will open up as the latest .NET core Windows Froms.